# DiscCache only first 10 - Fresco

Tags: android, fresco

I have implemented a facebook like app. I get data from a server, I display it using a recycler and store it in a sql database via a content provider. If there is no internet active I'm just displaying the stored data via a CursorLoader (10 items). My problem is that when I store fresco images in disk cache I can't specify to store only 10, but I'm displaying only 10 elements. If for some reason the connection is lost and there are only 5 images stored that's fine, but I wouldn't like to waste memory on storing images that won't be displayed. How can I go about this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can [configure the disk cache](http://frescolib.org/docs/configure-image-pipeline.html#configuring-the-disk-cache) to set a maximum size.